# Is this json array feasible to code in mvc.net Web API

Tags: arrays, json, asp.net-mvc-4

```
{    
    "myImage":
    [
        {   
            "Image":
            "/9j/4example="
        },

        {
            "Image":
            "/9j/4example="
        },

        {
            "Image":
            "/9j/4example="     
        },

        {
            "Image":
            "/9j/4example="
        },

        {
            "Image":
            "/9j/4example="
        }
    ]

}
```

Here there is one array named : myImage 
and under image array there are five key value pair named: Image

Is this right to give same name "image". If it is right then how my code will understand which image should be picked.

Comment: you need to have identifier for each image to be able to know which image need to be picked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should works. Your C# classes should looks like this:

```
public class MyImage
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<MyImage> myImage { get; set; }
}
```

But quite better JSON format suggested currapickt. Depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Change the json structure to something like this:

```
{
    "myImage": [
        {
            "Image": {
                "id": 1,
                "value": "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"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```